# Devise - undefined local variable or method `current_member'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using `members` as the Devise model. I have placed `before_action :authenticate_member!` in the application controller.

But when i try to use the following in the views

```
<%= current_member.inspect %>
```

Am getting the following error

```
undefined local variable or method `current_member' for #<#<Class:0x007fe48ad32130>:0x007fe48e389af8>

  #<Class:0x007fe48ad32130>#_app_views_brands_members_index_html_erb___144793605481589474_70309807670200
    app/views/brands/members/index.html.erb, line 1


<%= current_member.inspect %>

<%= link_to('Logout', destroy_brands_member_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

Member Model - `app/model/member.rb`

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  acts_as_paranoid

  # Associations
  belongs_to :company

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

end
```

**Devise Initialiser**

```
config.default_scope = :member
```

**Controller**

```
class Brand::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_member!

  private

end
```

Members Controller `brands/members_controller.rb`

```
class Brands::MembersController < Brand::ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

**ROUTEs**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # devise_for :members

  # Brands Routes
  constraints :subdomain => "brands" do
    scope :module => "brands", :as => "brands" do
    # namespace :brands do

      # devise_for :members

      devise_for :members, controllers: {
        sessions: 'brands/members/sessions',
        registrations: 'brands/members/registrations',
        confirmations: 'brands/members/confirmations',
        passwords: 'brands/members/passwords'
      }

      get '/members' => 'members#index'

    end
  end


  # API Routes
  constraints :subdomain => "api" do
    scope :module => "api", :as => "api" do

      api_version(
          module: "V1",
          header: { name: "Accept", value: "application/vnd.skreem+json; version=1" },
          defaults: { format: :json }
        ) do
          # devise_for :members
          # resources :products
      end


    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your model and its location?

Comment: Also have you run `rails generate devise member`?

Comment: @HarshaMV sorry but did you restart server?

Comment: i am able to signup and confirm the account etc.

Comment: so when you get this error?

Comment: When i try to access the helpers and check if the `member` is logged in. When i try to go to the signup page again also i can not so the sesssion is active.

Comment: `member_signed_in?` - what does this return to you

Comment: @dkp undefined method `member_signed_in?'

Comment: Post the relevant controller

Comment: @Matt i have nothing in the controller just a blank index action and `before_action :authenticate_member!`

Comment: please share your routes file too

Comment: @z.shan added it sir :)

Comment: issue is with your controller inheritance  i saw some pluralization's issue like "Brand::ApplicationController"  and  "Brands::MembersController" . try to create your own before action in Brand::ApplicationController and authenticate in this method.

Comment: @z.shan can you share some example?